# Code first implementation in Entity framework

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

Can any one help me... What are steps i need to follow Code first Implementation in EntityFramwork using ASP.NET MVC3. I'm Very new to Entity framework. So Please tell me step by step. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow [this introduction](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) made by Scott Guthrie, a Corporate Vice President in the Microsoft Developer Division.

I [posted two links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210130/asp-net-mvc3-where-can-i-learn-it-from/5210170#5210170) about some nice tutorials in ASP MVC 3. The Movie App tutorial uses the Code First method.
Regards.